# Kivy segmentation fault on blitting opencv picture

Tags: python, kivy, opencv

I am trying to cast video from my external cam, that is captured through some aliexpress EasyCap, to my kivy app. One issue I've faced is that crashes with segmentation fault on trying to

```
texture = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[0], frame.shape[1]))
```

I've found that the problem is on [kivy's side](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/5254). It sometimes can't create NPOT textures. So, I've changed it to POT shape and copied what is possible to another numpy array.

```
flipped = cv2.flip(frame, 0)
buf = np.zeros((512, 512, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
for i in range(min(frame.shape[0], 512)):
   for j in range(min(frame.shape[1], 512)):
      buf[i, j] = flipped[i, j]
buf = buf.tostring()
texture = Texture.create(size=(512, 512))
texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt="bgr", bufferfmt="ubyte")
self.texture = texture
```

But it still crashes with the same old segmentation fault on the following line:

```
texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt="bgr", bufferfmt="ubyte")
```

If it is relevant, cv2.imshow("image", buf) before buf.tostring() show the image correctly.

Here's the original code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
import cv2
import threading
from time import sleep
import numpy as np

class KivyCamera(Image):
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      super(KivyCamera, self).__init__(**kwargs)
      self.fps = 30
      self.capture = cv2.VideoCature(0)
      threading.Thread(target=self.update).start()

   def update(self):
      while True:
         ret, frame = self.capture.read()
         if ret:
            buf = cv2.flip(frame, 0).tostring()
            texture = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[0], frame.shape[1])
            texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt="bgr", bufferfmt="ubyte")
            self.texture = texture
         sleep(1.0 / self.fps)


class CamApp(App):
   def build(self):
         return KivyCamera()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   CamApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few issues with your code:

1. The GUI updates should always be done in the mainthread as indicated by [John Anderson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7254633/john-anderson). Hence instead of separate thread, the `update()` function should be called through `Clock` schedule.
2. The `size` tuple in the `Texture.create` statement should be reversed and the `colorfmt="bgr"` should be added. It should be: `texture = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt="bgr")`.
3. There is no layout defined. Layouts like `BoxLayout` should be added as a placeholder of `Image` widget.

Below is the modified working version of your code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
import cv2

class KivyCamera(BoxLayout):
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      super(KivyCamera, self).__init__(**kwargs)
      self.img1=Image()
      self.add_widget(self.img1)
      self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
      Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0/33.0)

   def update(self, *args):
     ret, frame = self.capture.read()
     if ret:
        buf = cv2.flip(frame, 0).tostring()
        texture = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt="bgr")
        texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt="bgr", bufferfmt="ubyte")
        self.img1.texture = texture

class CamApp(App):
   def build(self):
         return KivyCamera()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   CamApp().run()
```

The `while` loop is removed and `Clock.schedule_interval` is used with `1 / 33.` steps.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, that is indeed helpful!
For now, I've created a 512x512 texture in a separate function with @mainthread and updated it with a separately created numpy array, that is filled from the original image. And it worked!
Yet, could you please explain why the texture size is reversed?

Comment: OpenCV returns numpy array of the image. And the shape returns tuple in the order height, width and channels. But in Kivy Texture the size expects tuple in the order width and height. Hence shape[0] corresponds to height and shape[1] corresponds to width of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Not well documented, but I believe the `Texture` manipulation (specifically the `blit_buffer()`) must be done on the main thread. Your `update()` method is being run in another thread, so use `Clock.schedule_once()` to call a method that does the `Texture` manipulation (and the `self.texture = texture`) back in the main thread.